# Is there any version specific pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

Pokemon Let's go being a remake of Red and Blue, I wonder... is there, just like there was in Red and Blue, some pokemon that can only be caught in Pikachu or Eevee?

If yes, what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Let's Go Pikachu and Let's Go Eevee each have exclusive Pokémon that will allow you to catch<sup>1</sup> in each version. According to [this guide](https://screenrant.com/pokemon-lets-go-eevee-pikachu-exclusives/), the exclusives are:

**Let's Go Pikachu**

> Oddish, Gloom, Vileplume, Sandshrew, Sandslash, Growlithe, Arcanine, Grimer, Muk, Scyther, Mankey, Primeape

**Let's Go Eevee**

> Bellsprout, Weepinbell, Victreebell, Vulpix, Ninetales, Meowth, Persian, Koffing, Weezing, Ekans, Arbok, Pinsir

---

1. In Let's Go Pikachu, I was able to trade 5 Growliths for a Persian in Vermilion City. In Let's Go Eevee, a friend of mine was able to trade 5 Meowths for an Arcanine. I don't know all of these instances, but I do know of this exception.